# Using NodeJS development dependencies in Heroku review-app post-deploy step

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, dependencies, heroku-review-app

I have a (demo) application hosted on Heroku. I've enabled Heroku's "review app" feature to spin up new instances for pull request reviews. These review instances all get a new MongoDB (on mLab) provisioned for them through Heroku's add-on system. This works great.

In my repository, I've defined some seeder scripts to quickly get a test database up and running. Running `yarn seed` (or `npm run seed`) will fill the database with test data. This works great during development, and it would be perfect for review apps as well. I want to execute the seeder command in the `postdeploy` hook of the Heroku review app, which can be done by specifying it under the `environment.review` section of the `app.json` file. Like so:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "addons": [
    "mongolab:sandbox"
  ],
  "environments": {
    "review": {
      "addons": [
        "mongolab"
      ],
      "scripts": {
        "postdeploy": "npm run seed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, the seeder script relies on some development-only dependencies (`faker`, `ts-node` [this is a TypeScript project], and `mongo-seeding`) to execute. And these dependencies are not available in the `postdeploy` phase of an Heroku app.

I also don't think that "compiling" the typescript in the regular build step is the best idea. This seeder script is only used in development (and review apps). Besides, I'm not sure that would resolve the issue with missing dependencies like `faker`.

How would one go about this? Any tricks I'm missing?

Can I maybe skip Heroku's step where it actively deletes development dependencies? But only for review apps? Or even better, can I "exclude" just the couple of dependencies I need, and only for review apps?

Comment: Could you set you NODE_ENV to development in the app.json file?

Comment: Does that have impact on the dependencies that are available post deployment?

Comment: You're right! :D I haven't tested this but the docs confirm it: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#environments — @mhatch73 please submit that as an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: sorry took the weekend off, glad this helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation) indicate that when the `NODE_ENV` variable contains anything but `"production"`, the `devDependencies` will not be removed after the build step.

To make sure this only happens for Heroku review apps, you can set the `NODE_ENV` variable under the `environments.review` section of the app.json file. The following config should do the trick:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "addons": [
    "mongolab"
  ],
  "environments": {
    "review": {
      "addons": [
        "mongolab:sandbox"
      ],
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "postdeploy": "npm run seed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```